# How to disable Webview scrolling and set it's height to fit the entire content

Tags: javascript, webview, uwp

I am using webview to show and edit the content in my UWP application. I want to disable the scrolling within the Webview control and make it adapt the height just to fit the entire content it has. And then it should respect the scrolling of it's parent control's scrollviewer. I have uploaded a sample application on OneDrive here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhChIerZubKRjQKBH5nA0KGTtPYP

In the sample app, you can see that once you reach at the end of the scrollviewer, the webview will start scrolling within itself. Instead what I would like to do is, keep scrolling (the parent scrollviewr) to the end of the webview.

Edit: Here's the code:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" Height="200" Width="400">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Navigate web page 1"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="Button_Click"/>

            <Button Content="Navigate web page 2"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="Button_Click_1"/>

            <Button Content="Navigate web page 3"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="Button_Click_2"/>

            <Button Content="Navigate web page 4"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="Button_Click_3"/>
            <WebView Name="WebView" Width="400" MinHeight="200"></WebView>
        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private const string EditableParameter = "~editable~";
        private const string SetBodyEditableScript = @"
                try
                {  
                        document.body.contentEditable = '" + EditableParameter + @"';
                }
                catch(e)
                {

                }";

        private const string SetTextFromClipBoardFunctionName = "setTextFromClipBoard";
        private const string SetHtmlTextFromClipboardFunction =
                "function " + SetTextFromClipBoardFunctionName + @"(htmlFromClipboard) 
                {
                   if (window.getSelection) 
                    {       
                        var range;
                        var sel  = window.getSelection();
                        if (sel.rangeCount) {
                            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                            range.deleteContents();

                            var el = document.createElement('div');
                            el.innerHTML = htmlFromClipboard + '<span></span>';
                            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
                            while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
                                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
                            }
                            range.insertNode(frag);
                            range.collapse(false); 
                            window.external.notify('RefreshAndReportHtml');
                      }
                        else if (typeof document.selection != 'undefined' && document.selection.type != 'Control') {
                                var html = (node.nodeType == 1) ? node.outerHTML : node.data;
                                html += '<span></span>';
                                var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
                                textRange.pasteHTML(html);
                                textRange.collapse(false);
                                window.external.notify('RefreshAndReportHtml');
                      }
                    }     
                };";

        private const string GetHtmlFunctionName = "getHtml";
        private const string GetHtmlFunction =
                "function " + GetHtmlFunctionName + @"(skipParam) 
                {
                    return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
                };";

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MakeWebviewEditable();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //(Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(WebviewPage), "http://tsn.ua");
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //(Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(WebviewPage), "http://buzzfeed.com");
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //(Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(WebviewPage), "http://microsoft.com");
        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //(Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(WebviewPage), "http://cnn.com");
        }

        private const string EventNotificationFormat = @"window.external.notify('{0}');";
        private async void MakeWebviewEditable()
        {
            WebView.NavigateToString("I do not know how that about righting wrongs can be, said the bachelor, for from 707" +
                                    "straight you have made me crooked, leaving me with a broken leg that will never see itself straight again all the days of its life and the injury you have redressed in my case" +
                                    "has been to leave me injured in such a way that I shall remain injured for ever and the height of misadventure it was to fall in with you who go in search of adventures." +
                                    "I do not know how that about righting wrongs can be, said the bachelor, for from 707" +
                                    "straight you have made me crooked, leaving me with a broken leg that will never see itself straight again all the days of its life and the injury you have redressed in my case" +
                                    "has been to leave me injured in such a way that I shall remain injured for ever and the height of misadventure it was to fall in with you who go in search of adventures.");
            //await InjectJavaScriptAsync(SetBodyEditableScript.Replace(EditableParameter, "true"));
            await InjectJavaScriptAsync("document.designMode='on'");
            await InjectJavaScriptAsync(GetHtmlFunction);
        }

        private async Task InjectJavaScriptAsync(string jscript)
        {
            await WebView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Only execute JS if a document is fully loaded. This should eliminate JS exception related to UNKNOWN name errors.
                    //if (IsHtmlLoaded)
                    string result = await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { jscript });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

To autosize WebView according to its HTML content, we can try with following code:

```
private async void WebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var webView = sender as WebView;

    int width;
    int height;

    // get the total width and height
    var widthString = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" });
    var heightString = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });

    if (!int.TryParse(widthString, out width))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get page width");
    }
    if (!int.TryParse(heightString, out height))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get page height");
    }

    // resize the webview to the content
    webView.Width = width;
    webView.Height = height;
}
```

And then we can use this method in XAML like:

```
<WebView Name="WebView" Width="400" MinHeight="200" NavigationCompleted="WebView_NavigationCompleted"/>
```

Or in code-behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MakeWebviewEditable();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

    WebView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;
}
```

Here I used [WebView.NavigationCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationcompleted.aspx) event because we need to make sure  the current content has loaded before we try to get the content's width and height.

**Update:**

While on Windows 10 Mobile, above method might not completely work. This is because **WebView** on Windows 10 Mobile is **not compatible with parent controls** that require gestures to propagate up from the WebView control to the parent, such as [**FlipView**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview.aspx), [**ScrollViewer** class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx), and other related controls.

Ref **Remarks** of [WebView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx):

> By default, **WebView** content is hosted on the UI thread on devices in the desktop device family, and off the UI thread on all other devices. You can use the [**WebView.DefaultExecutionMode**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.defaultexecutionmode.aspx) static property to query the default threading behavior for the current client. If necessary, you can use the [**WebView(WebViewExecutionMode)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn932036.aspx) constructor to override this behavior.
>
> > **Note**  There might be performance issues when hosting content on the UI thread on mobile devices, so be sure to test on all target devices when you change [DefaultExecutionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.defaultexecutionmode.aspx).
>
> A **WebView** that hosts content off the UI thread is not compatible with parent controls that require gestures to propagate up from the **WebView** control to the parent, such as [**FlipView**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview.aspx), [**ScrollViewer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx), and other related controls. These controls will not be able to receive gestures initiated in the off-thread **WebView**.

As a workaround, usually we can try using something like

```
WebView WebView = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SameThread);
```

in code-behind instead of creating web browser in XAML to solve this problem. However as the **Note** said, hosting content on the UI thread on mobile devices is not a good practice and in my test, this will cause HTML content can't be editable. So this may be not an acceptable solution for your question.

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. Based on your requirement, you can try like @DecadeMoon said to put the buttons into HTML page. Or you can get the content of the HTML into a [RichEditBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx). Or you can change your layout and just put the WebView outside the ScrollViewer.

Comment: I tried it, it looks like it is setting the height correctly but the problem is scrolling event of the webview is causing issue in propagating to the parent ScrollViewer. So what's happening is, when I try to scroll the scrollviewer by tapping and dragging the webview it just ignores the scrolling since the webview's own scrolling event come into picture.

Comment: What if you were to disable scrolling in the WebView with a `overflow: hidden` style on the `body` (or `html`, I never remember which one) element?

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Sorry, I didn't notice that you are using this on Mobile. While on Windows Mobile, there are some differences. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I tried your updated code. It seems that the font size of the webview has decreased and there is a long empty space in the webview below the content. But yes, the scrolling issue is now gone. Also, another issue is that the webview is no more editable like it was earlier. Can we fix it?

Comment: @AshishAgrawal I'm afraid we have no way to fix it. It is related to the underlying implementation of WebView. As I've said in my update, using use WebView(WebViewExecutionMode) constructor may not an acceptable solution for your scenario. You may try with some other workaround or just put the WebView outside the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Okay, I suppose I will have to go ahead and rewrite the other controls (other than webview) in html/javascript to achieve it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Can you please confirm if your earlier solution (before the update) is supposed to work fine on WinRT devices. So I am testing on Surface Pro 4 and I am able to scroll through it just fine even if I touch the webview and swipe up/down. But on Windows phone 10, it does not scroll and webview would handle the scrolling within itself.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Yeah, it should be able to work on Surface. As the document said, `By default, WebView content is hosted on the UI thread on devices in the desktop device family, and off the UI thread on all other devices.` Surface is also considered as the device in desktop device family.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying you want the height of the `WebView` control to equal the height of the webpage it is displaying? I don't think that's possible. I imagine the `WebView` would employ some form of rendering optimizations such that it doesn't need to render what's not visible in the viewport. If the entire height of the webpage is visible, then it has to render everything which would be terrible for performance.

It looks like you're trying to control the webpage directly through the `WebView` by injecting javascript. You're going to have a hard time doing that. If there's no way to achieve what you want in XAML only, then maybe you can rewrite your app in WinJS instead?

---

The easiest way to achieve what you want would be to put the buttons directly in the webpage and notify the host when they are clicked so you can act.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="webView" ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify" Height="300"/>
</Grid>
```

**CS**

```
private void prepareWebViewContent()
{
    var html = @"
        <style>
            button {
                padding: 15px 20px;
                font-size: 40px;
                border: none;
                background-color: #ccc;
                font-family: inherit;
                display: block;
                margin: 10px auto;
            }

            button:active {
                background-color: #aaa;
            }
        </style>

        <button onclick=""window.external.notify('Navigate1')"">Navigate to web page 1</button>
        <button onclick=""window.external.notify('Navigate2')"">Navigate to web page 2</button>

        <p>
            I do not know how that about righting wrongs can be, said the bachelor, for from 707
            straight you have made me crooked, leaving me with a broken leg that will never see itself straight again all the days of its life and the injury you have redressed in my case
            has been to leave me injured in such a way that I shall remain injured for ever and the height of misadventure it was to fall in with you who go in search of adventures.
            I do not know how that about righting wrongs can be, said the bachelor, for from 707
            straight you have made me crooked, leaving me with a broken leg that will never see itself straight again all the days of its life and the injury you have redressed in my case
            has been to leave me injured in such a way that I shall remain injured for ever and the height of misadventure it was to fall in with you who go in search of adventures.
        </p>
    ";

    webView.NavigateToString(html);
}

private void webView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Value)
    {
        case "Navigate1":
            // Handle this case
            break;

        case "Navigate 2":
            // Handle this case
            break;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

It's very rudimentary, but you get the idea.

Comment: Actually it's a part of the existing application which is written in C#/WPF and it's not an option for me to rewrite it. So, I was wondering if there is a way to make those buttons a part of the webview itself (by injecting them into webview or something). I don't know if I am making any sense here by saying that but just wanted to check if it's a possibility.

Comment: It started making sense to me now. I have one question here, so in my real app, I have some custom wpf controls (AutocompleteTextBox) in place of those navigation buttons (in example). Can I use those wpf controls controls in the html like you used the button tags?

Comment: In hindsight, I probably shouldn't've suggested this answer because it is very hacky and difficult to extend (especially had I known you wanted a more complex UI than in the question). You can't mix XAML and HTML (meaning you can't put a XAML control into a WebView). So you can either (1) rewrite all XAML UI you want *within the WebView* into HTML and delegate events via `window.external.notify()`, or (2) try to get the WebView to play nicely with XAML per Jay's answer. (Also you'd have to port the WPF controls to the UWP if you choose the second option, but the XAML is very similar.)

Comment: I appreciate the help. Yes, I think it makes sense to me. I will see if Jay's solution works for me. If not, I am going to right the AutoCompleteTextBox in HTML as you said.